# Is there any packages support database ORMs in nodejs like model in Laravel (PHP)?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Nodejs and express, now I'm write pure query to
interact with database so I'm looking for packages support DB query. Thank in advance !

Comment: Check out [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/) and [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)

Comment: This is a subjective question, c.f. [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), in particular the bit below "avoid asking subjective questions where …"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm
more details visit their github ; https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm

I am using it with my NodeJS server and PostgreSQL DB